# What is the most Cross Platform C++ 2d and 3d game library?

Tags: mobile, operating-system, cross-platform

I am looking for VERY cross platform 2d/3d video game libraries for C++.  By VERY cross platform - I mean something that runs on Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, iOS, Nintendo consoles, Nintendo portables, Playstation consoles, Playstation portables, XBox systems, etc. (that's my goal anyway - but it should at least run on as many of those as possible).

I want to find as many such platforms as I can - then I'm going to look at comparing the costs for a small/single person developer license in those platforms.  Something that's free and open source is ideal, but I'm not too sure I can find that if it's going to be as cross platform as I want it to be

(To be clear I want to filter these libraries only AFTER I see them all, so don't worry about them being either too expensive or too cheap, I want to look at all the very very cross platform C++ 2d/3d game libraries that I can).

I know about OpenFrameworks and Cinder, but I'm not sure if those really are as cross platform as I am looking for.  OpenFrameworks for example, I think covers Windows, Linux, and just SOME mobile platforms such as Android, but not as many platforms that I would like to see it run on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have seen the marmalade SDK, but I am not sure whether or not that works on Nintendo, Playstation and XBox console and portable systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most cross platform library I know of is SDL coupled with OpenGL. It is open source and will run on any platform which has an open development model, namely PCs (Windows, Linux, Mac) and Android. I believe iOS is supported as well. Unfortunately often platforms such as Xbox and PLaystation have their own SDKs that make cross platform development difficult.

In such cases it may be more feasible to simply write library agnostic code and implement a wrapper for each target system. Most systems except for some microsoft platforms (Xbox) support some kind of OpenGL.